# Color attribute is adding a colored border in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Let me start by saying, I like the border that chrome is using for my inputs, my issue arrises for the textarea. The textarea is using the color attribute as a border as well as the intended function of coloring the inputed text. Here is my css:

`select, textarea, input{ font-size:25px; font-weight:bold; color: #FF4500;}`

As i said I want the border that chrome makes, I just dont want the colored border it puts around ONLY the textarea for some reason. There any way i can apply the color to just the text or maybe prevent the color attribute from changed the border color?

Comment: The behavior of applying `color` to borders is intended behavior: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#border-color-properties but I really don't think Chrome uses that by default for textareas; AFAIK it uses its own default borders until you override them. Which version are you using?

Comment: Oh, I didnt know that, none of my other browsers do that (firefox or IE) and Version 19.0.1084.56. Would you know how i can apply the color only to the text?

Comment: The only way is to give it a border color. Are you sure you don't have any `border` styles being applied to `textarea`, like in a CSS reset or something?

Comment: No I am not giving it a border color and as i said, Chrome is the only browser I see a border color in and as you can see I apply my css to input, select, and textarea but text area is the only one getting a border.

Comment: You may not be giving it a border color, but what about other border styles? Use your web developer tool and check your textarea to find out.

Comment: @BoltClock, does that link apply to the situation? It sounds like the link is saying that if a `border` is specified but a border-color isn't, the border defaults to the `color:`. Since this situation has no border being set, do you think the `color:` still applies? Am I making sense? So much color!

Comment: @Alex: You read it correctly. I'm saying that the behavior applies if and only if a border is set but not its color; at the same time, because as far as I'm aware this shouldn't happen to default textarea borders, I'm asking the OP if he has any border styles set on textarea that Chrome may be using to color its border.

Comment: could this be the culprit `-webkit-border-radius: 10px;` ?

Comment: why don't you just assign a border with the color you want?

Comment: Because i like to style chrome gives the box, and do not want to ruine that. But if i cant, thats what i will end up doing.

Comment: Yes, `-webkit-border-radius: 10px;` would be it. The moment you set any border property it will no longer use the default border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the setting (in code other than the part you posted) that sets border properties on `textarea`, such as `border-width` or `border-radius`.

The reason is such settings may make Chrome (or other browsers) use a normal border around an element, as determined by CSS properties on it, instead of the default border it draws with special routines that are immune to CSS. The effects vary by browser and by property. For example, with your example code, on Chrome, if you add `border-style: solid`, then an `input` element gets orange red border, but `select` and `textarea` keep their default gray borders. But if you add `border-radius: 8px` instead, then `input` keeps its default border color (though with rounded corners) whereas both `select` and `textarea` get orange red borders.

Comment: Yes thats seems to be the issue, Thanks. Wish I could add border radius and keep the chrome border style.